# Bulk manage Google Contacts with dual SIM card

Tags: contacts, dual-sim

I have a Archos NEON 45 with a dual sim option. Never had a use for it until my business phone stopped working. So I transferred the business SIM-card to my Archos NEON.
I also added by Google Business accounts in order to have the business contacts available on my phone. Now I have to choose which SIM-card to use when making a phone call.
There is the possibility to link a contact to a specific SIM-card. By now I have to edit all the business contacts manually to specify this link to the correct SIM Card. Is there a desktop app or Android app that can do this based on the groups I have specified in each contact?

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally stumbled upon a useable solution. In the Settings menu on the top is a menu item 'Manage SIM". This is meant for setting up names and defaults for the SIM cards. At te very bottom there is a menu item 'Link contacts' (translated from the dutch 'Contact verbinden'. 
Next step is to select the SIM card and then you can select contacts to link to the selected SIM card. (Don't forget to press the 'Add contact' icon at the top-right after selecting the correct contacts, instead of the checkmark at the top-left.......)